# Getting video metadata of a video stored in s3 bucket using aws lambda node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mediainfo

I have a video stored in aws s3 bucket I want to get the metadata of the video (like framerate, resolution, etc) inside aws lambda which is using node js runtime.

It will be better if this can be done in memory instead of downloading the whole video in lambda temp memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaInfo supports natively AWS, without having to download the file in a first step. MediaInfo downloads in RAM what it needs for the analysis, and does itself the seek requests when needed.

URL style is `https://AWSKey:AWSSecret@s3...`.
Using pre-signed URLs is also possible but the 20.03 version is buggy, you need to use [MediaInfo snapshots](https://mediaarea.net/download/snapshots/binary/mediainfo/).

Jérôme, developer of [MediaInfo](https://MediaArea.net/MediaInfo).

Comment: what if I use url from some other site will it be fully downloaded or partially to get the metadata?

Comment: I'm trying to use pre-signed URLs with version 19.09 and 20.03 and it's not working. The pre-signed URLs r working fine in the browser. How can i download more older version in aws lambda

Comment: I have also tried `https://AWSKEY:AWSSECRET@s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key` url and it's also not working

Comment: Behavior of MediaInfo is same on S3 or other sites. S3 is used by a lot of users, AWSKEY:AWSSECRET style is known (use by several sponsors) to be fine and pre signed URls buggy with 20.03 (19.09 and snapshots are fine). if you think there is an issue, please send the command with a real use case (URL or temporary key/secret) at info@mediaarea.net for debugging.

Comment: Okay. So, I downloaded the lambda zip file from the lastest snapshot and it's working previously I was downloading zip from the site. Thanks for making this tool

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch metadata of your video via the [headObject operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property).

This is done without downloading the actual content of the video.

**Edit**: You're right, this doesn't help you.
Extracting actual technical metadata of videos seems to be non-trivial. There's a good example on the [AWS blog where they extract metadata via MediaInfo on lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/extracting-video-metadata-using-lambda-and-mediainfo/).

Comment: data returned by headObject operation doesn't contain data like framerate, resolution, etc of the video. It contain data like contentLength, lastModified, etc.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I've edited my answer, maybe this of some help!